# Can I create a fake AP with my wireless card?

Tags: wifi, man-in-the-middle, wireless

I type `iw list` and these are the supported modes:

```
Supported interface modes:
                 * IBSS
                 * managed
```

When I run hostapd hostapd.conf I get this:

```
Failed to create interface mon.wlan0: -95 (Operation not supported)
Could not set channel for kernel driver
wlan0: Unable to setup interface.
Could not connect to kernel driver.
```

I have also tried this other path:

```
airmon-ng start wlan0

airbase-ng -e FreeWifi -c 11 -v wlan0
```

With this result:

```
ioctl(SIOCSIWMODE) failed: Operation not supported

ARP linktype is set to 1 (Ethernet) - expected ARPHRD_IEEE80211,
ARPHRD_IEEE80211_FULL or ARPHRD_IEEE80211_PRISM instead.  Make
sure RFMON is enabled: run 'airmon-ng start wlan0 <#>'
Sysfs injection support was not found either.
```

In case that helps for the troubleshooting my card is this one:

```
lspci | grep -i net
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82566DM-2 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 02)
01:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n (rev 03)
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you running those as root? In any case, you seem to be using the wrong interface. After you run the "airmon-ng start wlan0" command, you should see "mon0" interface being created. Any subsequent commands should use that instead of wlan0.

Answer (score 1):

In order to act as a proper access point, your card needs to support "master"/"AP" mode.  You can fake it if the card supports "monitor" mode with packet injection (in this case, your AP software will be performing many of the tasks that the driver/card would be performing in "master" mode), and you can get some of the functionality of an AP if your card supports "ad-hoc" mode (set up an ad-hoc network and configure your computer to route between the wireless and wired networks).

Answer (score 0):

When I perform `iw list` I have a third option, `monitor`.

```
Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
     * monitor
```

I think this is what your IOCTL failure is stemming from.  Your wireless interface needs to have a monitor mode.  Try the following command (as root) to enable `RFMON` and I believe it will fix your problem.

**iwconfig [interface] mode monitor**

Comment: operation not supported

Comment: Does your interface come up at all?  It sounds like you have a driver issue.

Comment: Yes ifconfig wlan0 up works (I fixed that problem before)

Comment: You might want to reinstall the Broadcom drivers, [using Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)?

Comment: I recently reinstalled them, I am using Debian 7

Comment: Ubuntu is Debian based, a lot of their solutions will apply.  You need RFMON enabled for what you're doing.  If your drivers don't support it, I'm not sure you can do.  I would search on Broadcom drivers to enable RFMON and see what pops up.